# Find maximizing region for triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given the following triple integral:

$-\iiint_D (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -4) \,dV$

How can I find the closed surface out of which the above integral is maximal? I am using the divergence theorem to calculate flux through a surface.

Comment: Would the answer just be a sphere of radius 4 centered at the origin?

Comment: I believe it should be a *closed ball* ($D$ should not be a surface, but a [volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_integral)) of radius $2$ centered at the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is maximized for the largest set $\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ for which $f(x,y,z) = -(x^2+y^2+z^2-4)$ remains positive, i.e., when
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2\le 4
$$
which is indeed the closed ball of radius $2$ centered at the origin.